# problema con el selector first-child

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Buenas estoy practicando creando un formulario con bootstrap.

```css
body{
            background-color: #74DBEF;
        }

        #contentPrincipal {
            background-color: #F6F5F5;
            margin-top: 30px;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }

        label {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #048998;
        }

      .columnaIzquierda div:first-child {
            background-color: #3BB4C1;
        } 

        input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
            font-style:oblique;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container" id="contentPrincipal">
          <div class="row"> 
              <div class="columnaIzquierda col-6">
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col text-center">
                            <h2>Registrate</h2>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <form action="" method="">
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-user"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-user"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="apellidos" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="dni" placeholder="Introduce tu DNI">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="edad" placeholder="Introduce tu edad">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="direccion" placeholder="Introduce tu dirección">
                                    </div>            
                                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="co-6">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="enviar" value="Registrar">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                  </div>                     
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col text-center">
                            <h2>Iniciar Sesión</h2>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col columnaDerecha">
                                <form action="" method="">
                                        <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-user"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre de usuario">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="enviar" value="Ingresar">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </form>
                        </div>
                  </div>
              </div>    
            </div>
          </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Mi problema reside en este selector CSS: `.columnaIzquierda div:first-child {
            background-color: #3BB4C1;
        }`

De la columna izquierda quiero seleccionar el primer div que la fila donde pone el titulo "Registrate" pero cuando visualizo en el navegador me pinta la columna entera, voy al inspector y efectivamente me pone que selecciona esa fila. Entonces no entiendo el porque me esta seleccionando todo. Si agrego una clase no hay ningún problema. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente añádele el selector `>` que hace referencia a los hijos directos y ya tendrás solucionado tu problema.

```
.columnaIzquierda > div:first-child {
   background-color: #3BB4C1;
}
```

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
body{
            background-color: #74DBEF;
        }

        #contentPrincipal {
            background-color: #F6F5F5;
            margin-top: 30px;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }

        label {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #048998;
        }

      .columnaIzquierda > div:first-child {
            background-color: #3BB4C1;
        } 

        input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
            font-style:oblique;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container" id="contentPrincipal">
          <div class="row"> 
              <div class="columnaIzquierda col-6">
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col text-center">
                            <h2>Registrate</h2>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <form action="" method="">
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-user"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-user"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="apellidos" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="dni" placeholder="Introduce tu DNI">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="edad" placeholder="Introduce tu edad">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="direccion" placeholder="Introduce tu dirección">
                                    </div>            
                                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="co-6">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="enviar" value="Registrar">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                  </div>                     
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col text-center">
                            <h2>Iniciar Sesión</h2>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col columnaDerecha">
                                <form action="" method="">
                                        <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-user"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre de usuario">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group input-group row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control col-7" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="enviar" value="Ingresar">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </form>
                        </div>
                  </div>
              </div>    
            </div>
          </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**EXPLICACIÓN:** Realmente tu estructura dentro del div con la clase `.columnaIzquierda` es así:

```
<div class="columnaIzquierda col-6">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-center">
              <h2>Registrate</h2>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
              ....
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Y lo que le estás diciendo con tu CSS es que escoja todos los divs que estén dentro de `.columnaIzquierda` y a su vez sean primer hijo de su elemento padre, por lo tanto, los dos divs que tienen la clase `.col` cumplen dicha condición, ya que están contenidos dentro de `.columnaIzquierda` y, a su vez, son primer hijo de sus elementos padre (los div con clase `.row`).

En cambio, usando el selector `>` lo que le estamos diciendo es que escoja cualquier div que sea hijo directo de `.columnaIzquierda` y a su vez sea primer hijo de esta.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Entiendo el porque, claro mi selector lo que hacia era seleccionar todos los primeros hijos y como tengo varios div dentro de otras, cumplen dicha condición y también se pintan... De nuevo gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @RonaldSanchez He agregado una pequeña explicación sobre el porque se produce este problema pero si, no ibas mal desencaminado ;)